# Python doesn't see installed module when running ipython

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, conda, geopandas

so I'm getting really nervous about that. I created a fresh new conda environment and installed there geopandas with its modules:

```
conda create -n geo2 -c conda-forge geopandas
```

So, then I'm activating the environment:

```
activate geo2
```

And then, just like I'd Taylor, I check it once, then I check it twice:

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

and the message is:

```
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\mikomi\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\geo2:
#
geopandas                 0.3.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
```

So, you'd think that's it, but no. When I run ipython from the conda environment:

```
ipython
```

and the try to import geopandas:

```
import geopandas
```

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e0ae602b2f92> in <module>()
----> 1 import geopandas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
```

I just dont understand this and it's driving me mad.

Additional info:

1) this is the output of sys.path:

```
['',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\.ipython']
```

2) This is the output of sys.executable:

```
'C:\\Users\\mikomi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\python.exe'
```

Comment: You need to open ipython from the conda env itself

Comment: I am doing that.

Comment: It's working fine in my system

Comment: well I'm happy for you

Comment: Try installing using pip

Comment: I tried to use pip but the managing dependencies with pip is hell

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because in the new Conda environment there was no Ipython installed. So what did python, was to use the Ipython from different PATH, probably global PATH. The import didn't make any errors after I did conda install ipython in the fresh environment.

Comment: That's what,I told you to open ipython from conda env

Comment: the Ipython was opened in my conda env

Comment: For such reason, I think miniconda, and nothing more on 'root' env is a lot better, to discover such errors.